# WPF tooltip in MS datagrid

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I show my business objects in a MS datagrid, containing "country", "city", "street", for example.
I can set a tooltip for each column showing its content using a style, so I get the "country" as tooltip when hooverinmg over the "country" column and so on.

But I did not succeed 
1) to show the content of "country" when hoovering over "city"
2) to show the content of some other property (not even displayed in the datagrid) when hoovering the datagrid

Any clues?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

Just define the Cellstyle like so

```
     <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource CellStyle}" x:Key="ToolTipErrInfo" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding /, Path=ErrInfo}" />
     </Style>
```

CellStyle is the parent Style without Tooltip